# Kendoui chart - stacked columns and dates

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

It seems that I just cannot get beyond this issue.This is an example of dataset:

```
[
{ type: "FOO", date: 1396952060722, count: 3 },
{ type: "BAR", date: 1396952060722, count: 2 },
{ type: "FOO", date: 1396952060722, count: 4 },
{ type: "BAZ", date: 1396952060722, count: 1 },
{ type: "FOO", date: 1396952060722, count: 3 },
{ type: "FOO", date: 1396952060722, count: 3 }
]
```

How can I make stacked column chart where X axis holds *dates* and columns are stacked by *type* with *count* fields summed (Y axis) if they fall under the same date.
I also need a way to regulate date granularity (year/month/day) and the data should distribute accordingly.

Is there a buildin way to do this or I'll have to make complex data transform?

Answer (score 1):

I've found this googling a bit:
[KendoUI - DataViz - Grouping and Aggregating a JSON datasource within the chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459097/kendoui-dataviz-grouping-and-aggregating-a-json-datasource-within-the-chart)
I believe this solves your problem.